# Flask Socket IO not Responding to WebSocket

Tags: python, websocket, flask-socketio, brython

I'm trying to create a Websocket connection from Brython to a local server running Flask and Flask-SocketIO.  The Brython code can connect to the Websocket echo server but when trying to use a local server it fails with error code "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200"

on the **client side** (using Brython):

```
def open_connection(event):
    global ws

    if not websocket.supported:
        alert("WebSocket is not supported by your browser")
        return

    # open a web socket
    # wss is websocket over SSL, ws is unencrypted 
    ws = websocket.WebSocket('ws://192.168.9.121:3000/message')
    #ws = websocket.WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org")
    print(ws)

    # bind functions to web socket events
    ws.bind('open', on_open)
    ws.bind('message', on_message)
    ws.bind('close', on_close)
```

on the **server** side:

```
 --- IMPORTS ---
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


# --- CONSTANTS ---
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 3000


# --- GLOBALS ---
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxxxxxx'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


# --- ROUTES ---
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/message')
def message():
    return render_template('message.html')


# --- SOCKETS ---
@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('Connected')
    emit('broadcast', {'data': 'Connected'}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('Disconnected')
    emit('broadcast', {'data': 'Disconnected'}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    emit('broadcast', {'data': message['data']}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on_error()
def error(e):
    print('Error', e)


# --- MAIN ---
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT)
    print('Connecting - ', HOST,  ':',  PORT)
    socketio.run(app, host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

The error code that shows up when trying to connect is:
brython.js:8666 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.9.121:3000/message' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Answer (score 1):

Note: Socket.IO is not a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a means of transport when possible, it adds some metadata to each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the ack id when a message acknowledgement is needed. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a WebSocket server (like ws://echo.websocket.org) either.

With that explanation, you need to use a socket.io client somehow in Brython which is currently unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

socket.io is not the same as WebSockets it does work over WebSockets though

Comment: while this clarifies that socket.io being able to work over WebSockets, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answers, you're using the basic web-sockets, whereas socketio has its own protocol.
You need to use the socketio libraries.

Brython supports [calling JS](https://www.brython.info/static_doc/en/jsobjects.html) functions and libraries.

Here's a snippet of brython which connects to my flask-socketio backend.

```
...
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brython/3.9.5/brython.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/python">
        from browser import window, alert

        io = window.io
        socket = io()
        def on_connect():
            alert('connected in Brython')
            socket.emit('join', {'room': 'asd'})

        socket.on('connect', on_connect)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're still having trouble, get it working with normal JS to prove its not something else.

JS equivalent

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        alert('connected in JS');
        socket.emit('join', {room: 'asd'});
    });
</script>
```